# Nightmarejs with Electron Proxies

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, nightmare, electron-vue

I've been trying to use nightmarejs in my electron-vue project. In dev everything worked fine, but after building, I would always get an error message. Luckily, I found this package which is a replica of nightmare but works in an electron-vue build: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eramthgin

Funny thing, everything worked as expected except for proxies (both in dev and build). However, when I used the eramthgin package directly with node, proxies worked.

I have tried changing the electron path, and adding nightmare in extraResources but none of them worked.

If you managed to get proxies working in nightmarejs/eramthgin in an electron-vue app, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.